# Py4J Serialization: AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute '_get_object_id'

Tags: python, apache-spark, serialization, pyspark, py4j

Using Py4J, I am not able to parse a Python dictionary object into the underlying JVM instance.

I have written a PySpark code where I'm running a UDF/lambda function on a RDD. My goal is to run a piece of Python code on each row of the RDD that requires to connect to the underlying JVM, per executor core, in order to get a Java class instance from a custom jar (source code is in Scala) that I deploy using --jars function during spark submit. I've tried the below example but get the mentioned error. This code runs on each executor core in a Spark 2.3 cluster with Cloudera distribution. Masked the code a little for security reasons.

```py
from py4j.java_gateway import JavaGateway, launch_gateway
gateway = JavaGateway().launch_gateway(classpath='custom-code.jar:scala-library-2.11.8.jar:spark-catalyst_2.11-2.3.0.cloudera3.jar:scala-reflect-2.11.8.jar', jarpath='<path-to-py4j-jar>/py4j-0.10.7.jar')
jvm = gateway.jvm
input_dict = {0: 123}
temp = jvm.com.my.code.PyUtil.fullMap(input_dict)

  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/SPARK2-2.3.0.cloudera3-1.cdh5.13.3.p0.458809/lib/spark2/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1248, in __call__
    args_command, temp_args = self._build_args(*args)
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/SPARK2-2.3.0.cloudera3-1.cdh5.13.3.p0.458809/lib/spark2/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1218, in _build_args
    [get_command_part(arg, self.pool) for arg in new_args])
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/SPARK2-2.3.0.cloudera3-1.cdh5.13.3.p0.458809/lib/spark2/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1218, in <listcomp>
    [get_command_part(arg, self.pool) for arg in new_args])
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/SPARK2-2.3.0.cloudera3-1.cdh5.13.3.p0.458809/lib/spark2/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 298, in get_command_part
    command_part = REFERENCE_TYPE + parameter._get_object_id()
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute '_get_object_id'
```

Oddly enough, when I run the exact same code, but call a different function of my custom jar, which takes in a String rather dict, it runs perfectly fine and I get a py4j.java_gateway.JavaObject back, which is what I intend to get here.

Looking at the release notes for py4j, I understand dictionaries have been supported since 0.5 version so I am not sure what exactly I am doing wrong here? I suspect something wrong with the gateway launch.

Any directional help would be appreciated.

Comment: After further exploration, I understand above code is launching a new gateway with the classpath, which is fine, but that gateway returns all `gateway._gateway_client.converters` as None. That is leading to the above error. Why would launching a new gateway not support any converters?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer, listed here:

https://www.py4j.org/advanced_topics.html#converting-python-collections-to-java-collections

I just had to convert it manually myself.

```
from py4j.java_collections import MapConverter
input_dict = {0: 123}
mc_run_map_dict = MapConverter().convert(input_dict, gateway_handle._gateway_client)
temp = jvm.com.my.code.PyUtil.fullMap(mc_run_map_dict)
```